# Replace character in file

Tags: python, regex, string, python-2.7

I decided to try to code a simple python script to edit some DNS zone file.
I've some lines, for example:

```
                IN      MX    10 mail.example.com
```

I want to replace the first space char of the line with '@', because it's missing in all files. I tried to use:

```
line.replace('                 IN  MX', '@                IN  MX')
```

and it doesn't work.

```
with open("zone_file.zone", "rw") as file:
    for line in file:
        line.replace('                 IN  MX', '@                IN  MX')
```

I also tried with list:

```
mx_before = list('                IN      MX')

for line in file:
    if line == str(mx_before):
        mx_before[0] = '@'
        "".join(mx_before)
```

and this neither.

I'd like to use some regexp and verify that there are no other chars before the IN string but I didn't realize yet how to do. What would be the best (not necessarily the simplest) method?

p.s.: I noticed the number of space chars is not fixed

Comment: why not `sed` or `awk`?

Comment: Hint: `string.replace` doesn't modify the string, it returns a new string that has your replacements. If you don't assign the result to something, it does nothing. Same for `string.join`.

Comment: @pavel they're well accepted. They didn't came to my mind, but I don't know them very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str="                IN      Mx"

for line in file:
    if str in line:
       line= "@"+line[1:]
```

try this demo:http://repl.it/Tbd

Comment: tiny! but how can I verify that the first letters after spaces are 'IN' and not others?

Comment: @bomba yes u can verify

Comment: thanks, but i also need to verify if there are some others char before the IN string.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import re

text = ' IN MX' 
text2 = re.sub('^\s', '@', text)
```

This function get the first space and replace it with '@'