# python edit file with if statement

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to check and edit some ns zone file using a python script, because they are missing the '@' symbol at the beginning of the string

```
            IN      MX    10 mail.example.com
```

I need some clarification on verifing if before the 'IN', there'are not any other strings or chars, just blank spaces.

Here's my code

```
with open("zone_file.zone", "r+") as file:
    for line in file:
        string = line.lstrip()
        if line.lstrip().startswith('IN     MX'):
            line = "@"+line[1:]
            file.write(line)
```

but it does nothing

basically the code is

```
for line in file:
   if str in line:
      line= "@"+line[1:]
```

but I need to check the presence of chars before the IN string

edit:
 I have:

```
                IN      MX
```

and I want

```
@               IN      MX
```

but the blanks spaces are not fixed

edit2: also the space between IN and MX is not fixed, so I can't figure out ho to solve.

this is an example of what I have

```
              IN      MX    20 mail2.example.com. 
              IN  MX    50 mail3              
example.com.  IN      A     192.0.2.1             
              IN      AAAA  2001:db8:10::1       
ns            IN  A     192.0.2.2             
              IN      AAAA  2001:db8:10::2
```

edit 3: this is my updated code, but it doesn't work yet

```
with open(filename, 'r+') as f:
    file_di_zona = f.readlines()
    for line in file_di_zona:
        if line.lstrip().startswith('IN') and 'MX' in line:
            line = '@' + line[1:]
            #print line
            file_di_zona.write(str(line))
```

Comment: Could you provide an example expected output as well? Also, as I am unfamiliar with NS Zone file standards, is the file fixed width so the 'IN' string will also be in the same position for each line?

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24039568/replace-character-in-file

Comment: @sundarnatarajサンダーナタラジ if there are chars I do nothing, if before IN there are blank spaces, I add '@'

Comment: @sundarnatarajサンダーナタラジ it does not modify anything

Comment: @sundarnatarajサンダーナタラジ I'm trying right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for line in file:
    if line.lstrip().startswith('IN') and 'MX' in line:
       line = "@"+line[1:]
       file.write(line)
```

best solution since if u have large file this will read fine and change it faster than normal

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
   if line.lstrip().startswith('IN') and 'MX' in line:
       line = '@' + line[1:]
   print line
```

save this as it is in a python file test.py

now go to the folder open terminal note both the test.py and ur zones file should be in same directory or give right path to read file

print the command

```
python test.py < zone_file.zone > modifiedzone.zone
```

Comment: i put a "print line" instead of the last "file.write(line)" and seems to work but the file doesn't change

Comment: I have no idea how to do it, I tried for hours, edit thousand times, tried also with temp files, but can't figure out how to use them.

Comment: the code works, but I need to edit multiple files after some other instructions. this is why I use the file methods. could you please add a solution that involves them?

Comment: @bomba please make sure the question starts from other requirement.dont show previous answers. they may regard as duplicate

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24064857/edit-one-line-across-multiple-files-using-file-methods-python